# Making 3D representation of an object with a webcam

Tags: image, image-processing, 3d, webcam

Is it possible to make a 3D representation of an object by capturing many different angles  using a webcam? If it is, how is it possible and how is the image-processing done?

My plan is to make a 3D representation of a person using a webcam, then from the 3D representation, i will be able to tell the person's vital statistics.

Comment: Yes, [this is entirely possible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEOmzjImsVc&feature=player_embedded), but explaining it all here goes a bit too far. If you're truly interested, the book "Multiple View Geometry" will be an excellent read for you.

Answer (score 2):

As Bart said (but did not post as an actual answer) this is entirely possible.

The research topic you are interested in is often called *multi view stereo* or something similar.

The basic idea resolves around using point correspondences between two (or more) images and then try to find the best matching camera positions. When the positions are found you can use stereo algorithms to back project the image points into a 3D coordinate system and form a point cloud.

From that point cloud you can then further process it to get the measurements you are looking for.

If you are completely new to the subject you have some fascinating reading to look forward to!

Bart proposed *Multiple view geometry* by Hartley and Zisserman, which is a very nice book indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As Bart and Kigurai pointed out, this process has been studied under the title of "stereo" or "multi-view stereo" techniques. To be able to get a 3D model from a set of pictures, you need to do the following:

a) You need to know the "internal" parameters of a camera. This includes the focal length of the camera, the principal point of the image and account for radial distortion in the image.
b) You also need to know the position and orientation of each camera with respect to each other or a "world" co-ordinate system. This is called the "pose" of the camera.

There are algorithms to perform (a) and (b) which are described in Hartley and Zisserman's "Multiple View Geometry" book. Alternatively, you can use Noah Snavely's "Bundler" http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/ software to also do the same thing in a very robust manner.

Once you have the camera parameters, you essentially know how a 3D point (X,Y,Z) in the world maps to an image co-ordinate (u,v) on the photo. You also know how to map an image co-ordinate to the world. You can create a dense point cloud by searching for a match for each pixel on one photo in a photo taken from a different view-point. This requires a two-dimensional search. You can simplify this procedure by making the search 1-dimensional. This is called "rectification". You essentially take two photos and transform then so that their rows correspond to the same line in the world (simplified statement). Now you only have to search along image rows.

An algorithm for this can be also found in Hartley and Zisserman.

Finally, you need to do the matching based on some measure. There is a lot of literature out there on "stereo matching". Another word used is "disparity estimation". This is basically searching for the match of pixel (u,v) on one photo to its match (u, v') on the other photo. Once you have the match, the difference between them can be used to map back to a 3D point.

You can use Yasutaka Furukawa's "CMVS" or "PMVS2" software to do this. Or if you want to experiment by yourself, openCV is a open-source computer vision toolbox to do many of the sub-tasks required for this.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with two webcams in the same ways your eyes work. It is called stereoscopic vision.
Have a look at this:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

An affordable alternative to get 3D data would be the Kinect camera system.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. My plan is to make a 3D representation of a person using a webcam, then from the 3D representation, i will be able to tell the person's vital statistics. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by vital statistics?

Comment: As noted, it can be done with one camera, as long as you capture multiple images from different positions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the answer you are hoping for but Microsoft's Kinect is doing that exact thing, there are some open source drivers out there that allow you to connect it to your windows/linux box.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. My plan is to make a 3D representation of a person using a webcam, then from the 3D representation, i will be able to tell the person's vital statistics. Is it possible?

Comment: The Kinect is not using stereo in that sense. It uses a structured light pattern to get range data.